# HTML canvas limit when draw functions are called too many times?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm learning some canvas stuff and am making a personal project with HTML/JS so pardon my ugly inelegant code.

In the code below, when only one of the a/b/c/d functions is called, everything works fine; but if more than one is called, then the canvas starts to freak out with weird [flickering colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UWe7.png). No error messages could be found in the console. The problem seems to subside when I decrease the number of tiles to be drawn but not the canvas size itself. I did call the canvas draw function a lot in other sections of the code so could these functions be the straw that broke the memory limit or something?

Help would be much appreciated! [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UWe7.png)

```
for (let y = 0; y < yCount; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < xCount; x++) {
        if (tileList[y][x] == 1) {
            a(x, y);
            b(x, y);
            c(x, y);
            d(x, y);
        }
    }
}

function a(x, y) {
    if (x != 0 && y != 0) { //! TOP-LEFT
        if (tileList[y][x - 1] != 1 && tileList[y - 1][x] != 1) {
            subfunctionTopLeft(x, y, palette[0]);
        }
    }
}

function b(x, y) {
    if (x != xCount - 1 && y != 0) { //! TOP-RIGHT
        if (tileList[y][x + 1] != 1 && tileList[y - 1][x] != 1) {
            subfunctionTopRight(x, y, palette[0]);
        }
    }
}
function c(x, y) {
    if (x != 0 && y != yCount - 1) { //! BOTTOM-LEFT
        if (tileList[y][x - 1] != 1 && tileList[y + 1][x] != 1) {
            subfunctionBottomLeft(x, y, palette[0]);
        }
    }
}
function d(x, y) {
    if (x != xCount - 1 && y != yCount - 1) { //! BOTTOM-RIGHT
        if (tileList[y + 1][x] != 1 && tileList[y][x + 1] != 1) {
            subfunctionBottomRight(x, y, palette[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

(The subfunctions are some custom draw functions.)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show a [mcve]--I don't see any canvas code here.

Comment: I'm sorry I think it may be a bug from Google Chrome or just the Chromium engine in general. If I keep refreshing the page in the same Chrome instance, the bug seems to persist. But when I start another Chrome instance or use another browser (in this case Edge), the problem seems to have solved itself.

So I guess this is not a canvas problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I think it may be a bug from Google Chrome or just the Chromium engine in general. If I keep refreshing the page in the same Chrome instance, the bug seems to persist. But when I start another Chrome instance or use another browser (in this case Edge), the problem seems to have solved itself. So I guess this is not a canvas problem.

Comment: Well, the code here isn't enough to reproduce the bug. Seems like you'd want to show that so other folks can see what steps are needed to reproduce the problem. If it really is a Chrome bug, then you can use this to file a ticket and help get it resolved. Without such an example, no action can be taken except voting to close.